# Why am i getting the output twice in the Node console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I have just started learning NodeJS, Kindly help me understand this

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In the Middleware');
    next();
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In another Middleware');
    res.send('<h1>Hello From Express</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Output is

```
In the Middleware
In another Middleware
In the Middleware
In another Middleware
```

Expected

```
In the Middleware
In another Middleware
```

Comment: How are you making a request to your server? From a browser? curl command? Something else?

Comment: I am doing this on my local server: node app.js on http://localhost:3000/

Comment: @ChetanBatra I tried running this but found nothing wrong with the output.

Comment: Right, but the middlewares won't execute until you actually  make a request to the server (e.g. like opening `http://localhost:3000` in your browser). How are you making that request?

Comment: https://repl.it/@pprathameshmore/NovelRoundScandisk You see here

Comment: yes i am opening  http://localhost:3000/ in my browser

Comment: Open dev tools and look at the Network tab. Then refresh the page. How many requests does the browser make to your URL? Sometimes browsers will make multiple requests (e.g. a CORS preflight request, a request to get favicon.ico file, etc.). Also, try running `curl localhost:3000` and see what the output is. Do you see the text output twice in that case?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the issue locally with "node server.js" and I see the middleware run 4 times (per page refresh). Once for the localhost:3000 request then 3 times for localhost:3000/favicon.ico so you might be getting your second console log during a favicon request.

Answer (score 5):

Browsers will often make multiple requests to a server. For example, they will usually try to fetch a `favicon.ico` file. Another example is a [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

If you open the [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) in your browser, go to the Network tab, and then refresh your page, you will see all the requests the browser makes (you may need to check the "Disable cache" checkbox first). If you see more than one request, that's probably the reason you're seeing your text logged multiple times.

Another simple way to test this is to try making a request to your server from a client other than your browser. For example, run this from the command line: `curl http://localhost:3000`. That command should make only a single request to your server. Do you see your text output multiple times in that case? If not, then that's further evidence your browser is making multiple requests to your server.

Comment: Adding to the above answer, you could also use Postman instead of curl which is super-easy to use. It is probably the go-to GUI tool to run these Rest API calls. Ideally, you should be testing with Postman or something similar to save your queries

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this happens because the browser usually makes a request for the favicon.ico as well, but you can check in the Network tab of the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using:

```
app.use('/',function(req,res){
    console.log('here');
})
```

So, I though whenever I refresh my frontend this should run once. But, browser actually sends multiple request whenever you refresh. (i.e favicon)

That's the reason your code logging multiple times.